# Scala: Why are Actors lightweight?

Tags: scala, actor

What makes actors so lightweight?

I'm not even sure how they work. Aren't they separate threads?

Comment: I'd like to add to this question:
How lightweight are Scala Actors?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When they say lightweight they mean that each actor is not mapped to a single thread.

> JVM offers shared memory threads with
>   locks as the primary form of
>   concurrency abstractions. But shared
>   memory threads are quite heavyweight
>   and incur severe performance penalties
>   from context switching overheads. For
>   an actor implementation based on a
>   one-to-one mapping with JVM threads,
>   the process payload per Scala actor
>   will not be as lightweight that we can
>   spawn a million instances of an actor
>   for a specific computation. Hence
>   Scala actors have been designed as
>   lightweight event objects, which get
>   scheduled and executed on an
>   underlying worker thread pool that
>   gets automatically resized when all
>   threads block on long running
>   operations. In fact, Scala implements
>   a unified model of actors - thread
>   based and event based. Scala actors
>   offer two form of suspension
>   mechanisms - a full stack frame
>   suspension(implemented as receive) and
>   a suspension based on a continuation
>   closure (implemented as react). In
>   case of event based actors, a wait on
>   react is represented by a continuation
>   closure, i.e. a closure that captures
>   the rest of the actor's computation.
>   When the suspended actor receives a
>   message that matches one of the
>   patterns specified in the actor, the
>   continuation is executed by scheduling
>   the task to one of the worker threads
>   from the underlying thread pool. The
>   [paper](http://lamp.epfl.ch/~phaller/doc/haller07actorsunify.pdf)  "Actors that Unify Threads and
>   Events" by Haller and Odersky
>   discusses the details of the
>   implementation.

[Source](http://java.dzone.com/articles/scala-threadless-concurrent)

Comment: If an exception is thrown, only the actor (and not the underlaying thread) will die right?

Comment: @someguy - I think it really depends on the implementation of the thread pool but yes.

Answer (score 0):

Important Reference [Actors that Unify Threads and Events](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~phaller/doc/haller07actorsunify.pdf)

I don't think we should strengthen that actor is that **lightweight**.

firstly thread based actors are actor per thread so not lightweight at all.

event based actors are the point where we start to feel actors are light weight. it is light weight because it does not have working thread wait and switched to another , working thread just switch from a piece of data work to another piece of data work, thus keep spinning on effective calculations.